# making a bending object

Tags: physics

What kind of methods are there to make object behave like it would be a spring , a metallic object
that bends just a little when you move it around, or like a piece of metal string .?,
that bends just a little when you move it around ( with a added hook )
when trying cloth simulator or softbody i can´t get it to come inflexible inaf.

Answer (score 2):

Rig your string with two bones at each end. Paint the Weight of how you want your spring to behave. For example: Heavy bending in the middle -> Red middle area to blue outter area.
then pin one bone to the hook.

Hope it helps. "weight paint" is the phrase you should look for

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  It sounds like this is the solution.  If you can, please add screenshots of the steps and expand on the process wherever possible.